# Recommended root partition size

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-one

I have 512 gb of hard disk. I want to install Ubuntu on it.

What should be the size of partition like root, home, swap? I also want to make a separate partition for storing own personal data like photo video etc.

Comment: Just do that. If you want all your data on a separate partition, 20 - 25 GB is enough for system files and user configuration data (home folder minus the actual user data). No need for a swap partition.

Comment: The "*just like in Windows*" idea in your head will cause you endless problems. Linux works differently -- embrace that difference. Advice: For your first install of Ubuntu, stick to the installer defaults. You can always add more complexity to your system later. You can always reinstall a more complex system after you understand how a successful install works.

Comment: The exact size recommends on what you are installing, and you've not said. A desktop recommends 25gb for / (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) however my own use-case shows I need 32gb (I bloat my system with lots of applications!). Many blogs say you can use smaller (they recommend nuke & clean-install rather than *release-upgrade* to later versions which means you need free space available)... so your end use-case will decide what you actually need.   How & what software will you add, do you want to *release-upgrade* to next release or re-install? etc

Comment: You've tagged lots of things - Ubuntu-ONE???  It's an SSO & how I login to this site (ie. I'm not logged into Stack Exchange but use Ubuntu-One) so I don't understand that connection at all. Ubuntu-One was a cloud service (now history) and today is SSO or single-sign-on service.  If you're using multiple desktops (you tagged 3) you need far more disk space than a single install too.

Comment: You didn't give release details, which is very critical for Lubuntu you tagged.  If you're talking about legacy Lubuntu (with LXDE) the requirements different esp. when combined with XFCE/Xubuntu, if contrasted to modern Lubuntu/LXQt or KDE/kubuntu. Mixing Qt & GTK adds disk space requirement as you'll have two sets of libraries installed (why I need more than 25gb; I'm using XFCE/LXQt/GNOME - but your tagging is unclear and you may mean something different to how I've understood it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to store your data files in your Ubuntu partition (that's actually a good idea), 60 gb for root (it is labelled `/` during installation) would be more than enough. As pointed out in the comments, 20-25 gb is enough for system files, but that may fill up quickly if you install too many software. 50-60 gb is always safe. In case you are using UEFI, you might also need to create a 512 mb `EFI` partition (if it's already not there in your hard drive).

You don't necessarily have to create a separate home partition or a swap. They are optional. If you go with the default settings, some part of the root partition will be shared for your home folder and swap, and Ubuntu will automatically take care of it for you.

To create a separate partition for storing personal data, you can either use gparted during the live session before installation, or the partition manager inside the installer itself.